# Should I install two 44 gallon well tanks or one 88 gallon?

Tags: plumbing, well

I have a 44 gal Water Worker well tank that is waterlogged and needs to be replaced, and I was looking to increase the volume  of pressurized water (the current size isn't cutting when I do any kind of irrigation).

My question is, what are the advantages/ disadvantages to say running two 44 gal tanks in tandem vs putting in a single 88 gal tank. Some of the pricing and availability seem to favor the 44gal, and  I have the spacing for two tanks.

Thoughts?

And thanks in advance

Comment: Curiosity - how old is the failed tank?

Answer (score 1):

There are replacement tanks with even more storage than your proposed 88 gallon size. If it were my decision to make, my choice would be for 1 tank to simplify the piping. That said, if the tanks are losing pressure when you have a prolonged water flow, the problem may be that your well or the well's pump does not have enough capacity. Even with a prolonged water flow the well and well pump should keep the pressure with-in the cut-in and cut-out pressures. With my last house that had a well and pump I could run my irrigation system all day and never loose water pressure or flow.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed, the system needs to be balanced. Depending upon water levels in the well and the location of the pump, it could even end up "sucking air" which is very not good! It always depends upon consumption vs. well production and pump capacity. +

Answer (score 1):

Two 40s or one 80 will be about the same in terms of storage.  But I think you have a different problem:  Even if your existing tank was working properly, 40 gallons is nothing when it comes to irrigation. 80 gallons is nothing when it comes to irrigation.   You need to match your usage (irrigation) rate to the capacity of the well pump and well production.  All well systems have unique characteristics.

If your irrigation is a sprinkler system, you may have to divide it into more zones to match your pump/well production.

Comment: Thanks for the edits isherwood....make the answer more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what you'd expect. Same volume, a bit more pipe, more likely to have one fail rather than both at once so you'd be a bit less urgent on replacing it next time, takes up a bit more room, but you have the room.